# How to make Outlook email signature mobile responsive or just responsive

Tags: html, outlook, dreamweaver, signature

I've got a problem with my email signature. I have designed it in Dreamweaver and when I add it to Outlook it changes the layout, it stretches my image and it's not mobile responsive.

I am not an email signature pro any help would be appreciated. Here is my code.

Here is an image to show what it does in outlook: [Email signature Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqBod.png)

*HTML*

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Email Signature</title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8"http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>

<body>
<table width="593" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 600px; 
font-size:9pt; font-family: 'Calibri Light', sans-serif;">
<tbody>
    <tr>    
        <td valign="top"  style="width:253px; vertical-align:top;">
            <a  href="https://www.tashascafe.com/media/1436/galaxy-bar- 
logo.png link URL"target="_blank"><img border="0"alt="Logo"     
width="250"style="width:250px; 
border:0;"src="https://www.tashascafe.com/media/1436/galaxy-bar- 
logo.png"></a>   
        </td>
            <td valign="top" style="width:338px; vertical-align:top;">
                <table width="340" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
                  style="border-collapse: collapse;">
 <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 338px; font-size:12pt; font-family:'Calibri 
             Light', sans-serif; font-weight:600; color:#85754e; padding- 
             bottom:5px; line-height:16px;">RESERVATIONS AT GALAXY 
             BAR</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size:10pt; font-family:'Calibri Light', 
             sans-serif; color:#000000; padding-bottom:1px; line- 
              height:14px; font-weight: 400;">
                    <span style="font-weight:600;">t: </span>+971 58 513 
                      0694
                </td>
            </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:10pt; font-family:'Calibri Light', sans- 
             serif; color:000000; padding-bottom:1px; line-height:14px; 
             font-weight: 400;">
                    <span style="font-weight:600;">e: 
</span>reservations@galaxy-bar.com
            </td>
        </tr>           

        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:10pt; font-family:'Calibri Light', sans- 
serif; color:#000000; padding-bottom:1px; line-height:14px; font-weight: 
400;"><span style="font-weight:600;">w: </span>www.galaxy-bar.com<a 
href="http://www.galaxy-bar.com"target="_blank"style="color:#000000"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:10pt; font-family:'Calibri Light', sans- 
 serif; color:#000000; padding-bottom:1px; line-height:14px; font-weight: 
 400;">
                <span style="font-weight:600;">a: </span>Unit C-01, DIFC, 
 Dubai, United Arab Emirates, 506609
            </td>
        </tr>                   

        <tr>
            <td style="padding-top:10px; vertical-align: bottom;"><span 
            style="display:inline-block; height:22px;"><span><a href=" 
            {facebookURL}"target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook 
             icon"border="0"width="20"height="20"style="border:0; 
              height:20px; 


  width:20px"src="https://www.tashascafe.com/media/1435/facebook-icon.png"> 
</a>&nbsp;</span><span><a href="{twitterURL}"target="_blank"><img 
alt="Twitter icon"border="0"width="20"height="20"style="border:0; 
height:20px; 
width:20px"src="https://www.tashascafe.com/media/1438/twitter-icon.png"> 
</a>&nbsp;</span><span><a href="{instagramURL}"target="_blank"><img 
alt="Instagram icon"border="0"width="20"height="20"style="border:0; 
height:20px; 
width:20px"src="https://www.tashascafe.com/media/1437/instagram- 
icon.png"></a></span></span>
        </td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>   
</tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will make it mobile responsive or not, but I can tell you how to prevent the distorting. 
Go into your signatures (Fastest way for me is to create a new email, click on the signatures tab, then select signatures)
Here is where you will want to create your signature, unless the whole thing is an image, then I would still create it and add you image. 
Once you do that, double click on the picture in the signature (sometimes you may have to double click on a different spot). 
A dialog box will appear, click on the size tab, then click absolute under height and under width. Under scale make sure lock aspect ratio and relative to original picture size is selected.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You must understand that Outlook is not a browser and actually uses the MS Word engine to render HTML. So, it's almost impossible that your Dreamweaver code (which is, sorry to say, very bad) will work in it.

You may read this article to get some tips: https://www.emailonacid.com/resource/outlook-coding-guide/

But keep in mind that writing HTML to e-mail is a completely different beast than writing it for modern browsers.